# Create multiple fields based in table

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have a table with agencies,

```
id | agency_name | agency_description
```

Then i need to have a form to save a value for each agency. The number of agencies is high, so, i am looking for a better way than explicit write a StringField for each agency. This could be done in the constructor when iterating over the table? What is the correct way to handle this type of situation?

```
class NewLimit(Form):
    ag_1 = StringField(lazy_gettext(u'Agency description ag_1'), [Required(), Length(1, 13)])
    ag_2 = StringField(lazy_gettext(u'Agency description ag_2'), [Required(), Length(1, 13)])
    ag_3 = StringField(lazy_gettext(u'Agency description ag_3'), [Required(), Length(1, 13)])
    ag_4 = StringField(lazy_gettext(u'Agency description ag_4'), [Required(), Length(1, 13)])
    ag_5 = StringField(lazy_gettext(u'Agency description ag_5'), [Required(), Length(1, 13)])
   ....
    ag_25 = StringField(lazy_gettext(u'Agency description ag_25'), [Required(), Length(1, 13)])
    submit = SubmitField(lazy_gettext(u'New limit'))
```

Comment: Why not use a select drop down box here?

Answer (score -2):

This is a good way but try using better memory saving technique like Structures in C language and declaring all fields Characters insted of integers.Hope this helped you.